# Writing data to Author site when using Cross site publishing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I have a question related to Cross-site publishing. We are in the process of building an Internet site on SharePoint 2013 On-premise. The architecture team in our company wants to leverage cross-site publishing and wants to avoid farm solutions. Hence we have gone the Add-in model way. Also, the author site and Publishing sites are separated into different web applications in order to keep the authentication for authoring site separate and to share data with other publishing sites from a common authoring web application. There is a scenario where we need to gather data from anonymous users and write this data back to author site for approval by authors. The approach that occurred to us was :

(1) Write data initially to publishing site using AppOnly permission Provider hosted app. 
(2) Move/Copy data to author site through a remote timer job installed on Author site. My question is How can we have remote timer job read data from Publishing site list ?

Any suggestions or alternative approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searching I came to the conclusion that an App/Add-in can have either permission scoped to the host web(site collection scoped) OR scoped to all site collections(tenant scoped). So it is either all or 1. I had to go with tenant scoped Write permission with CSOM code to do the job (using Remote timer job pattern : https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt204004.aspx) to achieve my goal. If there is a better way please let me know.